# Material-UI Drawer will not close and chrome shows a Warning: Unknown prop `onRequestChange` on <div> tag

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I have a material-ui navbar with a button on the left hand side, that button brings up a left hand drawer the only trouble is the drawer refuses to close on press of esc or on press of overlay.

I am using material-ui@next so the beta build of v1 so it is possible this is a bug with the material-ui people but given that I have never used the Drawer component before I thought I would check here first.

When I then click on the button at top left i get a drawer pop up but sadly I cannot remove it by hitting esc nor can i click on the overlay to remove it which I assumed was handled by

```
 onRequestChange={this.handleClose}
```

in components/LeftDrawer but instead i get a warning in chrome which reads:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `onRequestChange` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

React strips such props but in the documentation I am seeing this being onRequestChange being used for the Drawer so I really do not know what is going on here.

Hoping someone can point to the problem whatever it might be (hoping it is just the result of me being tired and at my wits end.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "history": "^4.6.3",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import App from './components/App'
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();

ReactDom.render(
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path="/" component={App}/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

components/App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import FinalAppBar from './AppBar'


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FinalAppBar/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

components/FinalAppBar.js

```
// @flow weak

import React from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import LeftDrawer from './LeftDrawer'
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Menu';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';

class FinalAppBar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            open: false
        }
    }

    //Toggle function (open/close Drawer)
    toggleDrawer() {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.state.open
        })
    }

    handleClose() {
        this.setState({open: false})
    }

    render() {
        const classes = this.props.classes;
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton color="contrast" aria-label="Menu"  onClick={() => this.toggleDrawer()}>
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
                            Title
                        </Typography>
                        <Button color="contrast">Login</Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <LeftDrawer open={this.state.open}
                            handleClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)}
                            onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

FinalAppBar.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const styles = {
    root: {
        marginTop: 30,
        width: '100%',
    },
    flex: {
        flex: 1,
    },
};

export default withStyles(styles)(FinalAppBar);
```

components/LeftDrawer

```
import React from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';

export default class LeftDrawer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};
    }



    handleClose() {
        this.props.handleClose();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Drawer
                    docked={false}
                    width={600}
                    open={this.props.open}
                    onRequestChange={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <li>Hello cruel world</li>
                </Drawer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Ok so this is what works perfectly in the latest stable version of react:

```
export default class FinalAppBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {open: false};

        this.handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

        this.handleClose = () => this.setState({open: false});
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar
                    title="Title"
                    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
                    onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle}
                />

                    <Drawer
                        docked={false}
                        width={200}
                        open={this.state.open}
                        onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
                    >
                        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
                    </Drawer>
            </div>)
    }
}
```

Going to work on proving the answer from logan below

Comment: Are you typoing `onRequestClose` as `onRequestChange`?

Comment: onRequestChange

Comment: obvious tiredness from my part thankyou!

Comment: Sounds we can close this as a typo then.

Comment: Well actually having had a look at it for a while I am convinced I should still be able to use onRequestChange, I am wondering if this is actually something that comes from    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"?

Noticed I am using require and its not defined obviously

Comment: Does `onRequestClose` not work then? "I am convinced I should still be able to use onRequestChange" based on what? Do you have a link to documentation or something?

Comment: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/drawer so this shows it is there in pre 1.0 version but the same cannot be said for 1.0; after then checking the supported components in 1.0 I notice Drawer is not ticked despite documentation on its use so it might just be that 1.0 drawers are not that far along yet, i will revert to latest stable and see what happens.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah I just looked at https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Drawer/Drawer.js and https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/internal/Modal.js and `onRequestClose` is all that is mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in Material 1.0 `onRequestChange` may have been changed to be `onRequestClose`.

The `Drawer` view does not mention either one and passes [all unknown props](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/9a6a3dde01d51de89c0b7ef3fd911cb3b8c798f4/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L183) through to [`<Modal />` here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/9a6a3dde01d51de89c0b7ef3fd911cb3b8c798f4/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L225) and in [`Modal.js`](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/internal/Modal.js#L358) the callback is `onRequestClose`.

This also appears to match the docs in the file itself: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/9a6a3dde01d51de89c0b7ef3fd911cb3b8c798f4/src/Drawer/Drawer.js#L124